# Function overloading vs function overriding across inherited classes in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

Consider the following piece of code

```
public class SuperClass
{
    //label 1
    void function(int a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    //label 2
    void function(int a)
    {
        a++;
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    //label 3
    void function(float a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }   
}
```

From what I have learnt, **label 2 is an example of function overriding** because a superclass method is being re-written in the sub class with its own implementation, while **label 3 is a form of function overloading** because the parameters are different while the function name is same.

My question is if label 3 is in fact function overloading, **which function is it overloading? Label 1 or label 2**?

**My theory is that label 3 is overloading label 2** because they are part of the same class.

I have come across these links -

[Does overloading work with Inheritance?](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/does-overloading-work-with-inheritance/)

[Different ways of Method Overloading in Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-method-overloading-java/)

while they provide useful information, they don't really answer my question.

This is only a conceptual question I had while learning polymorphism in Java. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is if label 3 is in fact function overloading, which function is it overloading? Label 1 or label 2?

Label 2, because the overloading only appears within `SubClass`. There is no overload in `SuperClass`. (Although you could argue that since label 2 overrides label 1, the answer is sort of "both," but in any context where the overload actually occurs, you'd have to have the override — e.g., you'd have to be dealing with a `SubClass` reference — so really it's just label 2.)

Comment: `Although you could argue that since label 2 overrides label 1, the answer is sort of "both"`. This is what I had initially thought, but i realized that function overloading is only for context of the same class. Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading occurs within a class, so, your assumption is correct.

> label 2 and label 3 are overloaded

Comment: Thanks for affirming my assumption. But I'll have to provide the other answer as 'accepted answer' because it goes into greater details.